# Product Gallery Images to go into full size on Product Page

Tags: images

I would like to find out. For those Product Gallery images, will it become the Product Image when you click or mouseover it?

I am unable to get it to display a bigger image. It just stays at the 1st image, without changing.

Is there anything I could do, so that when I click on whichever picture I want, it will display the bigger version?

I am using Flatsome theme on WooCommerce.

Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d8i9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, Jasmine. Can you please tell us what shopping cart system you are using (WooCommerce?) and what theme you are using? There are hundreds of shopping cart plugins for WordPress and thousands of themes. The steps required to accomplish what you want varies and people need to know which you are using in order to be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi I am using Flatsome theme on WooCommerce. Thank you. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. 1st time posting here. :)

Comment: Hi I am tried disabling plugins one by one and it helps to stop the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you know what plugin it was that was causing the problem, perhaps you could answer your own question for others in the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* gallery image size change in single product page */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', function( $size ) {
  return 'full'; // ‘full’ , ‘thumbnail’, ‘medium’, ‘large’
});
```

For more details please click [enter link description here](https://woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/)